# Prove that if square matrix rows are orthogonal unit vectors, so are the columns

Tags: linear-algebra

The title is pretty much the question, but to state it more explicitly:

If we construct a square matrix A to have rows that are orthogonal unit vectors, then $AA^{T}=I$, but how can we prove that $A^{T}A=I$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$AA^T=I$$

implies that $A^T=A^{-1}$.

Hence $$A^TA=A^{-1}A=I$$

Comment: Your first sentence part is wrong.  To prove that $A^{T} = A^{-1}$, you must prove both that $AA^{T}=I$ and that $A^{T}A=I$.  The second condition is exactly what I've asked how to prove.

Comment: Check out [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852/306553) for $21$ proofs of $AB=I$ then $BA=I$ which is basically left inverse is equal to the right inverse.

Comment: Ahah!  Thank you, that was the missing piece.